# Referenced array and unseting keys

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, pass-by-reference

I have this function that tries to filter an unknown array:

```
function removeEmpty(array &$array) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v) && count($v) == 0) {
                unset($array[$k]);
            } elseif ($v == '') {
                unset($array[$k]);
            } elseif (is_array($v)) {
                removeEmpty($v);
            }
        }
    }
```

The array could be of this type:

```
[
    'key1' => 'something',
     'key2' => [
         'level2' => 'something',
         'level2' => '',
         'level2' => [],
        ],
     'key3' => '',
     'key4' => [],
]
```

I know that unseting a variable through reference only breaks the binding to the variable, but is there any way to unset the keys of an array passed by reference?

Comment: What is the use case? Why would you want to do that? [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I edited the initial post to include the array type. I simply want to unset the empty values or the empty arrays

Comment: I don't think you can actually, you probably want to initialize a new array and iterate.